# When zooming in (ctrl+, ctrl-) my navbar won't go with?

Tags: html, css, web, nav

whenever I  zoom in on my webpage my navbar will go out of screen, when zooming out it's fine, is there maybe an attribute that will make it stay still when zooming/out or are there any other alternatives to fixing this?

```css
body, html {
    background-size: cover; 
    font-style: normal;
    font-family: "Lato";
    font-size-adjust: initial;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1,8em;
    color: #666;
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;
}

nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    min-width: 1200px; 
}
 
nav ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none; 
}

nav ul li {
    float: left;
    width: 210px; 
    height: 50px; 
    opacity: 0.8; 
    line-height: 50px; 
    text-align: center; 
    font-size: 20px; 
}

nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none; 
    color: white;
    display: block; 
    z-index: 1; 
}

nav ul li:hover {
    background-color: skyblue; 
    cursor:pointer; 

}

nav ul li ul li {
    display: none; 

}

nav ul li:hover ul li {
    display: block; 
    background: #282e34;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html> 
    <head>
        <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
<body>
 <nav>
  <ul>
   <li><a>Home</a></li>
   <li><a>Hardware</a></li>
   <li><a>Software</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a>System software</a></li>
        <li><a>Application software</a></li>
        
      </ul>
      </li>
    </li>
  <li><a>General Computers</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a>Types of computers</a></li>
        <li><a>History of computers</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  <li><a>Credits</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance. 
.........................................................................

Comment: Did you have any luck with my answer below? Please accept my answer if it solved your problem. We can also talk more about responsive css practices if you need more help.

Answer (score 2):

Could be because the nav has `min-width:1200px;`. If your screen size is less than 1200px then the navbar will bleed off the page and cause horizontal scroll.

I also changed the fixed width of the nav li elements to `width:20%` so they will shrink and grow with the nav.

```css
body, html {
    background-size: cover; 
    font-style: normal;
    font-family: "Lato";
    font-size-adjust: initial;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1,8em;
    color: #666;
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;
}

nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    /* min-width: 1200px; */ 
}
 
nav ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none; 
}

nav ul li {
    float: left;
    /* width: 210px; */
    width:20%;
    height: 50px; 
    opacity: 0.8; 
    line-height: 50px; 
    text-align: center; 
    font-size: 20px; 
}

nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none; 
    color: white;
    display: block; 
    z-index: 1; 
}

nav ul li:hover {
    background-color: skyblue; 
    cursor:pointer; 

}

nav ul li ul li {
    display: none; 

}

nav ul li:hover ul li {
    display: block; 
    background: #282e34;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html> 
    <head>
        <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
<body>
 <nav>
  <ul>
   <li><a>Home</a></li>
   <li><a>Hardware</a></li>
   <li><a>Software</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a>System software</a></li>
        <li><a>Application software</a></li>
        
      </ul>
      </li>
    </li>
  <li><a>General Computers</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a>Types of computers</a></li>
        <li><a>History of computers</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  <li><a>Credits</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```